# Aspect ratio for bitmap

Tags: android, xml, bitmap

Im trying to make a drawable xml resource to use as background for an activity. The background need to have a image at the top and one at the bottom. My problem is that the images doesn't keep aspect ratio and get stretch by height. How do I make them keep aspect ratio?

The popup_activity_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content">

<item>
   <layer-list>
        <item>
         <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:src="@drawable/popup_header"
              android:tileMode="disabled"
              android:gravity="top" >
         </bitmap>
      </item>

      <item>
        <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:src="@drawable/background_wizard"
             android:tileMode="disabled"
             android:gravity="bottom" >
        </bitmap>
      </item>
   </layer-list>
 </item>
```

I use the background for the root view in my activity layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="0dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:windowActionBar="false"
tools:context="com.xxxx.xxxxx.PopupAddxxxxx"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/popup_activity_background">
```

Comment: "@drawable/background_wizard", this Image must be creating issues, i.e. this Image must not be covering the whole screen. Right ??
Did you try to 9patch to this Image....!

Comment: Also try to change this line, <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">

to 

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content">

Answer (score 1):

Try `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in your bitmap

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:src="@drawable/background_wizard"
  android:tileMode="disabled"
  android:scaleType="fitXY">
</bitmap>
```

**Disclaimer:** Your image may look a bit blurry so try to 9Patch also.